# Dynamically return config value (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, config

I'm building a content middleware which gather contents from our external publishers. The publishers will share their contents either in rss or json and the key/value field would be different from each other. To make thing easier, I created a config file where I can pre-defined the key/value and the feed type. The problem is, how can I dynamically return this config value based on publishers name.

Example: To get Publisher #1 feed type, I just can use *config.articles.**rojak_daily**.url_feed*

my config file */config/index.js*

```
module.exports = {
    batch:100,
    mysql: {
        database: process.env.database,
        host: process.env.host,
        username: process.env.username,
        password: process.env.password
    },
    articles:{
        rojak_daily:{ // Publisher 1
            url: 'xxx',
            url_feed: 'rss',
            id: null,
            Name: 'title',
            Description: 'description',
            Link: 'link',
            DatePublishFrom: 'pubDate',
            LandscapeImage: 's3image',
            SiteName: 'Rojak Daily',
            SiteLogo: null
        },
        rojak_weekly:{ // publisher 2
            url: 'xxx',
            url_feed: 'json',
            id: null,
            Name: 'Name',
            Description: 'Desc',
            Link: 'link',
            DatePublishFrom: 'pubDate',
            LandscapeImage: 's3image',
            SiteName: 'Rojak Weekly',
            SiteLogo: null
        }
    }
}
```

my main application script

```
const config = require('@config'); // export from config file

class Main {
    constructor(){
      this.publishers = ['rojak_daily','rojak_weekly'];
    }

    // Main process
    async startExport(){
        try{
            for(let publisher of this.publishers){
                const feedType =  await this.getFeedType(publisher)
                const result = (feedType == 'rss')? await this.rss.start(publisher): await this.json.start(publisher)
                return result
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Error occured: ", err)
        }


    }

    // Get feed type from config
    async getFeedType(publisher){
      return await config.articles.rojak_daily.url_feed; 
      // this only return publisher 1 url feed.
      // my concern is to dynamically passing variable 
      // into this config file (example: config.articles.<publisher>.url_feed)
    }

}

module.exports = Main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async getFeedType(publisher){
    return await config.articles[publisher].url_feed; 
}
```

You can access properties of objects by variable

Comment: Thank you. You are my life saver. Its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could either loop over the articles by using [`Object.entries(articles)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [`Object.values(articles)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) in conjunction with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or since you already have the name of the publisher you could access that entry with `config.articles[publisher].url_feed`, like so:

```js
const config = {
  articles: {
    rojak_daily: { // Publisher 1
      url: 'xxx',
      url_feed: 'rss',
      id: null,
      Name: 'title',
      Description: 'description',
      Link: 'link',
      DatePublishFrom: 'pubDate',
      LandscapeImage: 's3image',
      SiteName: 'Rojak Daily',
      SiteLogo: null
    },
    rojak_weekly: { // publisher 2
      url: 'xxx',
      url_feed: 'json',
      id: null,
      Name: 'Name',
      Description: 'Desc',
      Link: 'link',
      DatePublishFrom: 'pubDate',
      LandscapeImage: 's3image',
      SiteName: 'Rojak Weekly',
      SiteLogo: null
    }
  }
}

const publishers = ['rojak_daily', 'rojak_weekly']

function getFeedType(publisher) {
  return config.articles[publisher].url_feed; 
}

publishers.forEach(publisher => console.log(getFeedType(publisher)));
```